# Liquibase : Error executing SQL SET DEFINE OFF

Tags: sql, oracle, liquibase

I'm using liquibase to execute oracle scripts. This oracle scripts, are executing merge into statements for oracle, this work fine, but the problem is that the data that I need to insert have strange characters, so in order to work we are using SET DEFINE OFF (at the beginning of the file) and SET DEFINE ON (at the end of the file) in order to avoid the errors.

But if I try to run the same script in liquiBase is not working and I get this error:

```
Liquibase Update Failed: Error executing SQL SET DEFINE OFF
```

My changelog looks like this:

```
<changeSet author="e-ballo" id="nopa_data_email" dbms="oracle" >
    <sqlFile path="email/NOPA_ACTIVATE_SECURITY.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" splitStatements="true" stripComments="true" />
```

Anyone know how to avoid this problem ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SET DEFINE` is not SQL but a SQL*Plus command.  SQL*Plus is an Oracle proprietary client, and most other clients (such as IDEs) don't recognise its commands.

The Liquibase forums suggest using CDATA as the best way to pass non-standard characters.  [Find out more](http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/imbedded-and-tag-characters-in-data-in-sql-statement).

Comment: Can you elaborate how to skip this from the script using Liquibase ?

Comment: @JITHIN - Sorry, it's been literally years since I touched Liquibase and I can't remember the details. Couple of notes. If you are happy to pay for licenses, FlywayDB Pro supports SQL\*Plus. [Check it out](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/oracle#sqlplus-commands). Although this isn't much help if you're already using Liquibase, and I don't think it's worth migrating: if you run Liquibase using SQL format scripts there's not much to be gained from FlywayDB.

Comment: Also @thatjeffsmith teased that Oracle will soon have Liquibase integrated with `sqlcl`, which would include your favourite SQL\*Plus commands.  [Find out more](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2019/01/19-x-sqlcl-teaser-liquibase/)